# Installing ArcGIS in Parallels

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, installation, mac, virtual-machine

I'm trying to install ArcGIS 10.1 Desktop Advanced Student Edition. I'm currently running Windows 8.1 on my Macbook Pro (2014, 16GB ram, 250GB SSD) using Parallels.

When I access the DVD from my USB optical drive, I can open up the ESRI.exe and the Quick Start Guide opens up as expected. I then click the 'Setup' hot button to the right of 'ArcGIS for Desktop', and a User Account Control window appears asking if I'd like to allow the program 'ArcGIS for Desktop 10.1 to make changes to this computer?'

I select 'Yes', at which point the User Account Control window disappears, and exactly nothing happens. The Setup does not begin. As well, the 'Install Guide' hot button to the right of 'Setup' does not link to a valid file.

Any ideas what could be inhibiting the installation?

Comment: Have you tried Running directly the ArcMap setup rather than getting there through Setup.exe? This file should be located on the DVD as well.

Comment: Did you get it set up? I just ran through it from scratch, and other than it appearing a little smaller than usual, seemed straight forward so far. I'm a huge mac lover, so I'm hopeful I can keep using it as I learn GIS.

Answer (score 3):

Just tumbled into this question. Activate full folder sharing between Mac and your VM Windows, then use finder to browse to the folder "Desktop" in the .iso file. Then click "setup.msi" and installation will begin without that setup menu. Another way is to copy all files in the .iso to your HD then run the regular setup.